# Changing an object change all the instantiated objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know that the topic of the question has been already asked and some answer have been given to it, but i'm asking it again because i fail misserably when i try to apply the answers from the other topics.

The problem that i have is that, i have a prefab (quad) 'Star' with a material into it and an script that makes it change color after some time:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Star: MonoBehaviour {
  public enum StarType {
    BRIGHT,
    DARK,
    F,
    K,
    L,
    P
  }

  private Ship ship;
  private StarType starType;
  private float timeLimit = .30f, timer;
  private System.Random rand;

  public void Awake() {
    ship = FindObjectOfType<Ship>();

    timer = .0f;
    rand = new System.Random();
  }

  public void Start() {
    refactor();
  }

  public void Update() {
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if(timer > timeLimit) {
        refactor();
        timer = .0f;
    }
  }

  public void LateUpdate() {
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(ship.transform.eulerAngles.x,
                                        ship.transform.eulerAngles.y,
                                        ship.transform.eulerAngles.z);
  }

  public void refactor() {
    starType = (StarType) rand.Next(0, 
             System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(StarType)).Length);
    switch(starType ) {
    case StarType.BRIGHT:
        renderer.material.color = Color.white;
        break;
    case StarType.DARK:
        renderer.material.color = Color.black;
        break;
    case StarType.F:
        renderer.material.color = Color.red;
        break;
    case StarType.K:
        renderer.material.color = Color.cyan;
        break;
    case StarType.L:
        renderer.material.color = Color.green;
        break;
    case StarType.P:
        renderer.material.color = Color.magenta;
        break;
    }
  }

  public StarType getStarType() {
    return starType;
  }
}
```

And this stars being instantiated in a Chunk class:

```
public class Chunk : MonoBehaviour {
  public Star star;

  private IList<Star> stars;

  public void Awake() {
    stars = new List<Star>();

    Star auxStar = (Star) Instantiate(star, transform.position, 
                      Quaternion.identity);
    auxStar.transform.SetParent(transform);

    stars.Add(auxStar);
  }
}
```

I was assuming that each star would change the color independently, but instead of that they all change to the same color.

I've tried using sharedMaterial instead of material as i read it on some asnwers, though the result and behaviour seems the same?, and i tried giving random init colors to the stars, but the most that i get is having a few of them changing to a color different from the rest, though still the same between them (And i'm trying to change colors all the time, not only upon creation).
I've read too creating a material and asigning to each one at instantiating, but i had no luck:

```
auxStar.renderer.material = (Material) 
                                 Instantiate(star.renderer.material);
```

Does someone know how can the problem be handled?

Comment: I think using Instantiate to clone the material should work. Did you use this just after you instantiated auxStar? Don't use sharedMaterial unless you make separate materials for each color, and then don't change those materials, just which one you use.

Comment: Used it after the Instantiate call yes, and before setting the parent. I'll have to check in more detail the shared material property too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using Random.Range() As in System.Random is generated by system time. As we know that Time is not Really Random. It still depends on mil sec times and generate the the logic of Random as we can't really tell which mil sec the random will run.

Since System.Random runs on 1 timeline which your scripts are using. Random.Range() is a bet you can consider since it uses SystemTime and independent time On Run of the platform. Shares with Time.DeltaTime.

Comment: Don't know why it's downvoted, changing System.Random actually fixed the issue. Didn't know that it would make any difference, i mean, each star instantiated would have a different mili, right? anyhow, it's something that i wouldn't have aimed to, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Unity API reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html), you are doing the right thing.
The issue in your code is that you are instantiating a MonoBehaviour

```
public Star star;
...
Star auxStar = (Star) Instantiate(star, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

where *star* is a MonoBehaviour, you are not instantiating the actual GameObject with the Mesh Render and/or Material. Instead make sure you are instantiating the right GameObject Prefab, not just the component, like this:

```
public GameObject starPrefab;
...
GameObject starClone = (GameObject) Instantiate (starPrefab);
Star auxStar = starClone.GetComponent<Star> ();
```

In that way you have control of the GameObject, if you need, and every component associated with the Cloned Object, in this case *Star*. You don't have to instantiate the Prefab Material cause it will be already instantiated.
Here is a simple Example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnStar : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject StarPrefab;
    public bool InstantiateStar = false;

    void Update () {
        if (InstantiateStar) {
            GameObject starClone = (GameObject)Instantiate (StarPrefab);

            float r = Random.Range (0f, 1f);
            float g = Random.Range (0f, 1f);
            float b = Random.Range (0f, 1f);
            float a = Random.Range (0f, 1f);

            starClone.renderer.material.color = new Color (r, g, b, a);
            InstantiateStar = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Side Note: Make sure to not modify the Prefab during gameplay since is the source of all other cloned objects.

Comment: Changing System.Random() for Random.Range() fixed the issue, but from your answer i got a little question. Is it that different instantiating the complete GameObject other than the component needed?, i mean, in other codes i've instantiated the component that i needed and didn't notice any issue, should i have done it with GameObjects all the time?

Comment: My mistake, According to the [API](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html), you can instantiate a Component as well and it will clone the entire GameObject. Nevertheless be careful cause the structure of the prefab as GameObject may differ from the structure of the component.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) next time i try to reference the prefab i'll check what structure i really want :)